# Eclipse CDT debugger "No source available for adress 0x..."

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I'm linking my C-program against a library (elf-format). Compiling and linking works fine. Now I want to walk through my program including parts of the library with the debugger. When I jump into a library-function I can see the disassembly but not the C-source. This is not a suprise since I didn't tell Eclipse where the C-sources of the library reside. And so I added the C-source files of the library as another C-project to my workspace and added the workspace path to this project as a source search path in the debug options of my main project. When I right-click on a function-call of a library-function within my code and choose "Open Declaration" Eclipse also brings me to the correct function. But debugger keeps telling me "No source available for address 0x....". Where is the problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you linking against a debug build of the library? The debugger needs debug symbols in any loaded binary to match up instruction addresses with lines of code. That's part of what "debug builds" are normally for (the main other part being disabling optimisations).

Comment: Ah ok. This could be the problem. How can I determine if the library contains debug symbols?